# How to keep SQL setting "sql mode" unchanged after reloading OpenServer?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to remove "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY" from "sql mode" in PhpMyAdmin, but each time I reload OpenServer, it return back.
What can I do to keep my changes?

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html says:

> To make a global system variable setting permanent so that it applies across server restarts, you can persist it to the `mysqld-auto.cnf` file in the data directory. It is also possible to make persistent configuration changes by manually modifying a `my.cnf` option file...
>
> For more information about persisting system variables and the mysqld-auto.cnf file, see [Section 5.1.9.3, “Persisted System Variables”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/persisted-system-variables.html).

Read those manual pages for more details.

That said, **you should not disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.** This SQL mode is enabled for a good reason, to prevent you from writing invalid SQL queries.

Comment: "Management of the mysqld-auto.cnf file should be left to the server. Manipulation of the file should be performed only using SET and RESET PERSIST statements, not manually" - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/persisted-system-variables.html

Comment: Yep, as I said, read the manual pages for more details.